# My method doesn't stop when it reaches a return statement

Tags: java

Question is answered: I was unknowingly calling the method twice.

```
 private int findBranch(int branchNumber){
    if(branches.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("branches.size() == 0");
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<branches.size(); i++){

        if(branches.get(i).getBranchNumber() == branchNumber){
            System.out.println("Branch found");
            return i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    return -1;
}
```

This code is supposed to search an ArrayList for an alement containing a given int.

If the ArrayList is empty, it's supposed to return 0 and stop. Otherwise it's supposed to loopthrough the ArrayList and check each element for the presence of the given int.

If the int is found it will return it's index.
If not found, it returns -1.

However, I constantly see an output with both printlines("branches.size() == 0" and "Branch found")

That shouldn't be possible for as far as I understand. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's simply not possible for a method to continue running after executing a `return` statement. You're calling the method twice.

Comment: please share more code

Comment: Can you post the code calling the findBranch method?

Comment: @BoristheSpider it is possible, in a finally block. Not the case here but I feel it's important to uphold the SO tradition of pedantic nitpickery.

Comment: @pvg true - I have updated my comment. Keep up the pedantry!

Comment: You can verify Boris's theory by putting a println as the first statement.  I bet it prints that statement twice.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're right and I'm an idiot. Thanks anyway. I still had a system.out, I used as a test, which called this method.

Answer (score 3):

> If the ArrayList is empty, it's supposed to return 0 and stop

Lists and arrays are 0-indexed, so that the first element has index 0.

You should return something else in case the list is empty, like `-1`, so as not to confuse with the case where the found element is at the first position:

```
if (branches.size() == 0) {
  System.out.println("branches.size() == 0");
  return -1;
}
```

Apart from that, any one of those `println` statements will only run once per execution of your method, since they're immediately followed by a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unknowingly, I was calling the method twice.

```
 public void addNewBranch(int branchNumber) {
    if(findBranch(branchNumber)<0 || branches.size() == 0) {
        branches.add(new Branch(branchNumber));
        lastBranchNumberAdded = branchNumber;
    }

    System.out.println("findbranch: "+ findBranch(branchNumber));
}
```

That System.out at the bottom was just there for testing. I deleted it and, as expected, all my problems were solved.